# fgets and fsetpos responsable negative pointer?

Tags: c

My problem is quite a situation I just cant get behind.
2 functions seem to confuse me the most and if might be a small thing I am overlooking but judging from my results, I just don't see it.

There are other problems similar to mine. Jet I chose to open this question because I think it might lead to a simpler explanation on the other 2 questions boards. Although the one is in Cpp and not C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
   FILE *fp;
   char buff[255];
   char objname[255];
   int i,fs,con;
   float var,x,y,z;
   char ch;
   fpos_t fpos,fend,fbeg;


   fp=fopen("test.obj","r");
   if (fp == NULL) 
   {
      printf("\nUnable to open file.");
   }
   fgetpos(fp,&fbeg);

   fgetpos(fp,&fpos);
   printf("\nfpos1 : %d",fpos);

   ch='m';

   while (ch!=EOF){
       ch=fgetc(fp);
       printf("%c",ch);
   }

   fgetpos(fp,&fpos);
   printf("\nfpos2 : %d",fpos);
   rewind(fp);
   //fsetpos(fp,&fbeg);   //works if I use this instead if rewind

   fgetpos(fp,&fpos);
   printf("\nfpos3 : %d",fpos);

   NSCAN:
   while (ch != '\n'&& ch!=EOF){
       ch=fgetc(fp);
       printf("\n %c",ch);
   }

   fgetpos(fp,&fpos);
   printf("\nfpos4 : %d",fpos);

   for(i=0;i<20;i++){
        objname[i]=fgetc(fp);

   }
   objname[20]='\0';

   fgetpos(fp,&fpos);
   printf("\nfpos5 : %d",fpos);
   //ch=fgetc(fp);

   fgets(buff,255,fp);

   fgetpos(fp,&fpos);
   printf("\nfpos6 : %d",fpos);

   printf("\ninbuff : %s",buff);
   printf("\nobjname : %s",objname);

   fclose(fp);

   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
    fpos1 : 0# Blender v2.76 (sub 0) OBJ File: ''
# www.blender.org
mtllib test.mtl
o Cube
v 1.000000 0.093909 -1.000000
v 1.000000 0.093909 1.000000
v -1.000000 0.093909 1.000000

vn 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 -0.862400 -0.506300
vn -0.000000 -0.862400 0.506300
vn 0.506300 -0.862400 0.000000
usemtl Material
s off
f 1//1 2//1 3//1 4//1

f 11//5 12//5 14//5
f 14//5 12//5 18//5 17//5

fpos1 : 0# Blender v2.76 (sub 0) OBJ File: ''
# www.blender.org
mtllib test.mtl
o Cube
v 1.000000 0.093909 -1.000000
vn 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 -0.862400 -0.506300
vn -0.000000 -0.862400 0.506300
vn 0.506300 -0.862400 0.000000
usemtl Material
s off
f 1//1 2//1 3//1 4//1
f 8//2 7//2 12//2 11//2
f 1//3 5//3 6//3 2//3
f 16//14 15//14 19//14 20//14
f 11//5 12//5 14//5
f 14//5 12//5 18//5 17//5
 
fpos2 : 1723
fpos3 : 0
fpos4 : 0
fpos5 : -43
fpos6 : -25
inbuff :  0) OBJ File: ''
```

The important part is where the pointers return a negative position.
I shortened the info on the Vertex's. 
For some reason if you set the position with 'fsetpos' it works.
I marked the part.
Yet that shouldn't have any influence 
I don't understand.
In an earlier version it was other way round.
If could understand why the pointer is negative id be a step further in understanding C in general.

I'd greatly appreciate the help.
Thanks

Comment: missed the end of the output:

Comment: objname : # Blender v2.76 (sub
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 2.335 s
Press any key to continue.

Comment: Do not ignore compiler warnings. If you don't get any, enable them. Then remove the cause. Your code may invoke undefined behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the response. fpos is not a ponter though... or am I mistaken...

Comment: What is the actual type of `fpos_t` on your platform ? If it's a 32 bit integer, then is it possible that it gets larger than 2^31 which will be printed as a negative numbr by `%d`.

Comment: This loop: `ch='m';

   while (ch!=EOF){
       ch=fgetc(fp);
       printf("%c",ch);
   }` is problematic in that it tries to print `EOF` as if was a character (it isn't!).  It should be: `int ch; while ((ch = getc(fp)) != EOF) printf("%c", ch);` where you have a different (more correct) type for `ch` — the members of the `getc()` family of functions return an `int`, not a `char` — and you test whether the character just read is EOF before trying to print it.

Comment: `fpos_t` is not defined by the standard to be a specific type. Assuming it is an `int` is plain wrong. (No idea how to get an integer from this, though)

Comment: @MichaelWalz: According to the standard it can be any type, except an array.

Comment: Your code `fp=fopen("test.obj","r");
   if (fp == NULL) 
   {
      printf("\nUnable to open file.");
   }` is not ideal; if the file fails to open, you report the problem (but error messages should go to `stderr`, not `stdout`) and then continue — that's not a good idea.

Comment: the warnings i get are for transfering fpos_t to int. and unused variables. using int representation has worked so far in other programs though.

Comment: @svenchan: Please first read what **undefined behaviour** means. There is a plethora of information about that to be found by a simple search.

Comment: @svenchan _the warnings I get are for transfering fpos_t to int_ : that seems to explain your issue: undefined behaviour.

Comment: `fpos_t fpos, ... printf("\nfpos2 : %d",fpos);` may not print the correct data.  Use `printf("\nfpos2 : %jd", (intmax_t) fpos);` or `printf("\nfpos2 : %lld",(long long) fpos);`  Still printing `fpos_t` is problematic.

Comment: fpos_t is defined as a long

Comment: `fpos_t` may be the same as `long` _on your system_. But `fpos_t` is certainly not defined by a standard to be `long`.

Comment: @svenchan: This is not portable. A new version of your standard library can change this already. You just should not rely on this.

Comment: e.g.  on my system is a `struct` composed by a long int and another `struct` with `union` inside...

Comment: ok, i get that part. but how does using rewind. change the behavior much lower in the program.

Comment: Im only using that as reference to know where the pointer is. the actual issue is that fgets is not acting predictably. to me atleast. I will redo my program.

Comment: Debug suggestion: file functions return a value indicating success/failure.  This code is having trouble, yet the return value of `fgetpos(), fgets(), rewind()` is not tested - this is not robust code.  Save time: 1) Use the correct return type of `fgets()`--> `int` and 2) check return values of IO functions.

Comment: @svenchan: You got an answer. If that did not answer your question, feel free to leave a comment asking for clarification. Otherwise please remember the stack overflow way to say "thank you for your time" is to accept an answer and/or upvote.

Answer (score 0):

According to the standard, `fpos_t` can be "*a complete object type other than an array type*" ([7.21.1p2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.1p2)).

Thus `printf`ing an `fpos_t` with `%d` type specifier does invoke *undefined behaviour* - unless it is `int` by chance. As there are no guarantees about its type, you must not rely on a specific type. Just don't `fprintf` `fpos_t`.

Enable compiler warnings and pay heed to them. In C a warning is always to be treated seriously.